# How to increase counter in file naming?

Tags: python, xml, filenames, file-writing

I am writing xml files and want to add a number to the end of an xml file name if a file with the same name already exists so I get:

```
info_for_john_0.xml
info_for_john_1.xml
info_for_john_2.xml
```

This is my code currently:

```
def pxml(listofdata):
    root = et.Element('INFORMATION')
    et.SubElement(root, 'last_name') = listofdata[0]
    et.SubElement(root, 'phone') = listofdata[1]
    et.SubElement(root, 'email') = listofdata[2]

    tree = et.ElementTree(root)
    ctr = 1
    for i in tree.iter('last_name'): # should be person_id
        name = i.text

    if os.path.exists(f"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml") == True:
        tree.write(f"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml")
        ctr += 1
    else:
        tree.write(f"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml")
```

However, all I am getting is:

```
info_for_john_0.xml
info_for_john_1.xml
```

and after that is just continually rewrites over info_for_john_1.xml. I suspect that is because I declare ctr = 1 in the function so every time it is called the value of ctr gets reset to 1.

I have tried making ctr a global variable and accessing, so like this:

```
ctr = 1

def pxml(listofdata):
    root = et.Element('INFORMATION')
    et.SubElement(root, 'last_name') = listofdata[0]
    et.SubElement(root, 'phone') = listofdata[1]
    et.SubElement(root, 'email') = listofdata[2]

    tree = et.ElementTree(root)
    count = global ctr
    for i in tree.iter('last_name'): # should be person_id
        name = i.text

    if os.path.exists(f"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml") == True:
        tree.write(f"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml")
        count += 1
    else:
        tree.write(f"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml")
```

but I receive a Syntax Error that count = global ctr is invalid syntax. I am unsure how else to access global variables. **--EDIT--** solved below, changed to:

```
global ctr
count = ctr
```

Comment: You need to indent the `if-else` block inside the for-loop. Python is indentation sensitive!

Comment: why would it need to enter the for loop? in this case all the for-loop does is iterate through the xml document and stores the person's last name in the variable 'name'. It's just meant for file naming purposes

Comment: I honestly don't know what you are doing here, you need to provide a [mcve]. You mention something about a function, but there are no function definitions in your code.

Comment: Apologies I am new to stackoverflow. I have included the full function for clarification. All I am trying to do is when I write the xml file, if there is someone with the same last name it writes the xml file as info_for_{last name}_{a number}.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
tree = et.ElementTree(root)
for ctr,i in enumerate(tree.iter('last_name')): # should be person_id
    name = i.text
    tree.write(f"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml")
```

Comment: I have tried this and I am still only getting info_for_John.xml and info_for_John_1.xml

Comment: This still isn't working, now it only produces one file (info_for_John_1.xml), I even added ctr += 1 to update the counter and it is not updating the counter no matter what

Comment: try to append name of files in a list  ie `"info_for_{name}_{ctr}.xml"` append this to a list, check if all the element in list , what are the element, if the list come with the real no of actual file name , then you need to see th e functionality of `tree.write`,

Comment: I tried that and it is appending the name to the list, however my counter is not going past 1, it only counts 0, 1 and then stops. If I set my counter to 1 it doesn't go past 2, it only counts 1, 2.

Comment: @then that mean len(tree.iter('last_name')) is 2 , 2 element in last_name

Answer (score 0):

Change `count = global ctr` to

```
global ctr
count = ctr
```

and see if that works

Comment: That did remove the error, thank you! However I am still unable to create files past info_for_john_1.xml